# Ng-click Defined in Directive Not Firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to call a function that is defined inside of my directive's class from my directive's template.

Consider the following template:

```
<div class="ef-jcrop">
        <img
             src="placeholder"
             ng-attr-alt="{{image.ImageName}}"
             ng-src="{{image.url}}" />

        <table>
            <tr class="ratio-selection">
                <td class="ratio-item" ng-repeat="group in aspectRatioGroups">
                    <img ng-src="image.url" class='ratioSelector' ng-click="selectCrop(group)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

The problem is the `ng-click` which calls `selectCrop()`, defined in the class for my directive.

```
module MyProject.Directives {

export interface IEfJcropScope extends ng.IScope {
    image: MyProject.Image;
    aspectRatioGroups: _.Dictionary<ImageProductDimension[]>;
}
export class EfJcrop implements ng.IDirective {
    restrict = "E";
    templateUrl = TEMPLATES + 'ef-jcrop.html';
    replace = true;
    transclude = true;
    scope = {
        image: "="
    }
    link = (scope: IEfJcropScope, elem, attrs) => {}
controller = ($scope: IEfJcropScope) => {}
selectCrop = (group: ImageProductDimension[]) => { .
//my function is defined here

  }
}
}
angular.module("mymodule").directive("efJcrop", () => new MyProject.Directives.EfJcrop());
```

This is TypeScript, for those unfamiliar. Most of it is very similar to JavaScript, though, as I translated it from JS. For some reason, `selectCrop` never fires. Is there a reason for this that I'm missing?

Comment: You need to bind your function to scope

Comment: What's the correct way to do that? I've just tried adding `selectCrop(group: ImageProductDimension[]);` under the `aspectRatioGroups` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attached the selectCrop function to $scope. I dont know how to write TypeScript but here it is in JS:

```
$scope.selectCrop = function(){...}
```

$scope is the glue between the controller and the view. Also, you need to inject $scope when you declare your controller for the view

Comment: How do I inject $scope? Sorry, I'm new to AngularJS.

Comment: This article is a great introduction to AngularJS. You will find what you need here: http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/

Also this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

Comment: This is not a complete answer.  In order to put selectCrop on $scope, it needs to be inside either the link or controller functions.  This is how to get a proper reference to $scope as well.